# Why does Naruto's clothes not burn after wearing the Kyuubi cloak?

Tags: naruto

I was watching Naruto Shippuden, episodes 35 to 45, and it is said many times that Naruto's skin burns when under Kyuubi's chakra effects. In those episodes, we see Naruto's skin is ripped off by Kyuubi's cloak when transforming into fourth tails.

Why does Naruto still have clothes after Yamato reverts the 4 tailed state? If Kyuubi's chakra destroys what is under the cloak, shouldn't Naruto be naked after Yamato's jutsu?

Comment: because they cannot show a fully naked Naruto!!!

Comment: The issue of clothes has always been a plot hole in Naruto. I think in order to keep the show family friendly and appropriate for its target audience, clothes always seem to be untouched.

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing are side effects to what's actually happening; exposing oneself to a bijuu's unfiltered chakra doesn't come at a cheap cost to the user.

The jinchuriki forms vary, but in essence, [the host is regarded more as an endoskeleton](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Jinch%C5%ABriki_Forms#Version_2) when transforming beyond Version 2 into partial and full tailed beast mode.  A shroud of chakra surrounds the jinchuriki which is in the shape of (or is part of the shape of) the tailed beast within.  From that, it stands to reason that their host is underneath the layers of chakra, quite well-clothed.

Comment: If I remember correctly, it was mentioned by Jiraiya that the Bijuu chakra actually 'burns' Naruto to the extent that we see his skins peel off and turn to ashes. The red colour of the Bijuu form is due to his blood mixing with the Bijuu chakra. Naturally, with Kyuubi chakra's healing powers, his skin cells are able to regenerate but there is no reason for his clothes to regenerate as well besides family censorship.

Answer (score 1):

This my understanding on the matter.
Kyuubi's chakra destroys any thing in touch with it if they have chakra. Since the clothing is not a living thing and is not receiving any chakra from any where and does not have a chakra flow in it, it will stand unharmed. But the skin has chakra points and a flow of chakra, so Kyuubi's chakra cloak will connect with it and because the skin is not strong enough to handle and channel Kyuubi's unfiltered chakra, it will burn away.

Comment: Do you have any sources for this?

Comment: as I said, this is my understanding of this. merely an opinion. should have posted it as a coment